# Close the dialog box when clicked any where else out of the dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my [JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/b6cjtbv2/)
I want to close the dialog box when clicked out of the dialog box. 
I used the following code but not fortunate to perform the task. Need help

```
 $(document).click (function (e) {
        if (e.target != $('#fb-like-popup-button')[0] || e.target != $('#fb-popup-contact-us')[0] || e.target != $('#fb-popup-subscribe-us')[0]) {
            $('#fb-popup-dialog-box').hide(400);
        }
    });
```

Comment: See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Events/blur so you need something like`$("#fb-like-popup").on("blur", function() { /*here code for hiding*/ });`

Comment: are you sure that you don't want to use `&&` instead of `||` ? I tried (modified your fiddle) in Chrome and seems to work

Comment: As @LohmarASHAR says, just change || to && and everything seems to work. This is updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b6cjtbv2/1/

Comment: Not working  but yes I have changed the logic to  close the dialog box.

Comment: Kindly take a look https://jsfiddle.net/b6cjtbv2/3/
I have changed my logic. If user clicks on "KEEP IN TOUCH" the dialog box closes but after closing the box if mouse is moved the dialog box reappears.